# Undefined property: ::$save

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php

I have been setting up a controller to save my data.

```
...
if ($this->Fee->save{$data}) {
...
```

But i am getting this error

> undefined property: Fee::$save

Full code as follows:

```
App::import('Model','Fee');
    $this->Fee = new Fee();
    $fee = $this->Fee->find('first',array('fields'=>array('Fee.amount','Fee.id')));
    $this->set('fee',$fee);
    if(!empty($this->data)){
      $this->Fee->set($this->data);
      if($this->Fee->validates()){
        $data           = array();
        $data['id']     = $fee['Fee']['id'];
        $data['amount'] = $this->data['Fee']['amount'];
        $this->Fee->set($data);        
        if($this->Fee->save{$data}){
          $this->Session->setFlash('<div class="success">'.__('AMOUNT_SAVED_SUCCESSFULLY',true).'</div>');
        }else{
        }
      }else{
        $this->set('errors',true);
      }
    }
```

I am using this in admins controllers `admin_fee` action. I am importing the model fee there. My model file is `fee.php` and name is `Fee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

```
$this->Fee->save($data)
```

Parenthesis instead of curly brackets